# Why can't I share a folder on Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, permissions, network-shares, windows-domain, shared-folders

On Windows Vista, I right-click on a folder, Properties, Sharing tab, and either "Advanced Sharing" or "Share"->"Share" causes an error:

```
Windows File Sharing
This program will not run
Access is denied.
                    Close
```

My user account is an "administrator" on this machine.

I think this behavior changed since my computer was added to the new domain recently.  I have other folders shared (from long ago), and they continue to be shared just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I've been fighting this all week, and somebody came up with a fix for me just now, so I'm recording it here!)

The hunch is that Windows' access control widget doesn't realize it needs to run, for some reason.  Maybe I'm just special?  Similar machines with (apparently) the same permissions on the same network don't exhibit this problem.

The workaround:

- Start Menu, right-click on Computer, Manage
- (this causes the "Windows needs your permission to continue" warning -> Continue)
- go to System Tools -> Shared Folders -> Shares
- right-click in the empty area, New Share..., etc.

This way, it gets elevated permissions out of the way before touching anything related to file sharing ever happens.  Problem solved!

Comment: +1, You can accept your own answer as the Solution. This will not work for Windows 7, "new share" is no longer available.

Comment: Yep, but I have to wait 2 days to accept it.  :-)